# How to do some computations on DF for a certain group and year

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a following data structure and want to draw a plot after implementing the following computation:
`share <- (df[,4]/sum(df[,4]))^2` by **year** so that I can draw two yearly plots of shares for each group on the same plane like below (scale of x and y axis are just randomly chosen).

(This is called HHI index, **I want to plot a single trend line of HHI plot by year**)

Could you help?

```
structure(list(kiscode = structure(c("350257", "500607", "351253", 
"320498", "351156", "360252", "360317", "360228", "380911", "381152", 
"310140", "310166", "370274", "310026", "350648", "310123", "350117", 
"380806", "320129", "340251", "370118", "370177", "370150", "360287", 
"360090", "380784", "351350", "370053", "310190", "381160", "380938", 
"380733", "310590", "351067", "310476", "350451", "310174", "340324", 
"310433", "350320", "381250", "310131", "320099", "340154", "320218", 
"350591", "380989", "380954", "380474", "360155", "320293", "350729", 
"320536", "350940", "320242", "380725", "320692", "380377", "370070", 
"320730", "350478", "380407", "370088", "350745", "350354", "350893", 
"370355", "370266", "350281", "320234", "350826", "351245", "330019", 
"350664", "100013", "320102", "350605", "381519", "320234", "320536", 
"381497", "350427", "310476", "370169", "350940", "360090", "380377", 
"320307", "351067", "310239", "380989", "360341", "350672", "320692", 
"381225", "310026", "500607", "380784", "370177", "360279", "350605", 
"320129", "350729", "350893", "351253", "380180", "370150", "350478", 
"350044", "310247", "370070", "381250", "380725", "380644", "350109", 
"350117", "382892", "320242", "351075", "320498", "380938", "360309", 
"350354", "350508", "340251", "310166", "350257", "320099", "381519", 
"350338", "370274", "310425", "340324", "360228", "350826", "380407", 
"320293", "330019", "320684", "351245", "350664", "310433", "310204", 
"380954", "350222", "370118", "320730", "310174", "352691", "351350", 
"350591", "360244", "320218", "380130", "320722", "310123", "351229", 
"320226", "380075", "351202", "380733", "310590", "380911", "350451", 
"320102", "351270", "360317", "351237", "370266", "310131", "310140", 
"370088", "320706", "350320", "360155", "380458", "310190", "351040", 
"380148", "381160", "350648", "100013", "350281", "351156", "381152", 
"350745", "370053", "360252", "360287", "340154", "350605", "350109", 
"380148", "320684", "350893", "350354", "500607", "350990", "320218", 
"310476"), format.stata = "%6s"), year = structure(c(1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982
), format.stata = "%9.0g"), group = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), asset = structure(c(18285348000, 
131784602000, 62865288000, 33838416000, 6360425000, 541330024000, 
22984591000, 132764602000, 213239161000, 6541576000, 49222411000, 
14139029000, 21186479000, 24339944000, 28434461000, 34758175000, 
17158988000, 15005232000, 217819358000, 25009066000, 58045333000, 
36533137000, 41099893000, 57162344000, 83874586000, 44872170000, 
45377311000, 28931137000, 30997921000, 6330526000, 50391070000, 
16471520000, 44011174000, 130526305000, 47629107000, 16930929000, 
76886460000, 29793379000, 110228999000, 4901957000, 13125490000, 
32708711000, 46811999000, 26297430000, 159598422000, 36722653000, 
14065113000, 299788090000, 4559409000, 16989303000, 5749583000, 
11320038000, 7566338000, 375368800000, 72924040000, 255463903000, 
36229805000, 84495668000, 147094202000, 134657126000, 18782347000, 
253086691000, 13385963000, 16256468000, 23786698000, 47589241000, 
8763943000, 187501484000, 6170263000, 93930236000, 91398637000, 
791687216000, 30833118000, 25927689000, 33738516000, 38081496000, 
20336333000, 74751893000, 191479919000, 10653474000, 6876018000, 
13974417000, 46282129000, 17031189000, 363957318000, 108913679000, 
99681110000, 12349372000, 153999084000, 63909181000, 19277127000, 
81424045000, 11976339000, 40404825000, 13215386000, 25694216000, 
218146702000, 50509180000, 46809912000, 8186674000, 26102731000, 
261698899000, 16279150000, 76399748000, 72255263000, 84773886000, 
53674439000, 20085234000, 9232070000, 12270735000, 152733380000, 
13605821000, 290913632000, 28622103000, 9080301000, 28835122000, 
898727627000, 79616356000, 17597661000, 37693427000, 70049637000, 
39413617000, 29126200000, 8434708000, 36338306000, 18034628000, 
17198072000, 62211779000, 112464191000, 37197557000, 25438818000, 
206704722000, 45275691000, 141347351000, 108806329000, 306891682000, 
6972372000, 38738858000, 55206596000, 895706255000, 32565599000, 
114178659000, 56217409000, 349187101000, 46372238000, 73244335000, 
146703938000, 84758892000, 76188179000, 51280724000, 44309538000, 
65066954000, 196115732000, 52854113000, 75028310000, 47956445000, 
40110855000, 140101705000, 27473652000, 4121326000, 25702217000, 
40537799000, 246498647000, 19932395000, 33344051000, 5409390000, 
24963711000, 7037719000, 235262813000, 40815511000, 66612981000, 
16495717000, 163887186000, 6185102000, 18941997000, 49019044000, 
40537839000, 17564451000, 49208650000, 9704707000, 28922397000, 
34829185000, 10982438000, 9184309000, 6185990000, 16737065000, 
31329834000, 644676975000, 88048087000, 26251573000, 27469120000, 
7539382000, 49168982000, 57080458000, 99468197000, 33985447000, 
295995241000, 16875791000, 209381233000, 57214594000), format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: what does 5 represent is ```df[,5]```?

Comment: And please share your expected outcome and clarify what exactly you want to do per group and year.

Comment: It's 5th column, which is asset.

Comment: That's actually the 4th column. Your example doesn't even have 5 columns, i.e. check `dim(df)` which gives `200 4`.

Comment: sorry, you are right. let me correct it. thanks

Comment: what is x and y in the plot?

Comment: x is year and y should be HHI index

Comment: I repeat myself, please share your expected data outcome. In the current state, you'll get several values for e.g. group 0 in year 1980, which then doesn't make sense to plot. What you need is ONE value per each group/year combination. Hiowever, this is not what you describe above in your formula.

Comment: Sorry I confuse myself. In fact the computation should be done only by year not group. Let me revise it. This means I will need only one time plot not two. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you still want to group by group. But if not you can easily take it out of the code below.

Comment: Sure, let me do so. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE! Ok, new try after googling myself about the hhi, which is the sum of squared shares.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  mutate(share = asset/sum(asset) * 100,
         year = as_factor(year),
         group = as_factor(group)) %>%
  summarize(hhi = sum(share^2))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
  year  group      hhi
  <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
1 1980     0  391.3174
2 1980     1  896.2375
3 1981     0  292.5786
4 1981     1  632.0987
5 1982     0 4134.3289
6 1982     1 4088.3348
```

And then you can plot with:

```
df_new %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_line(aes(x = year, y = hhi, group = group, color = group))
```

[image]

Comment: No, I just want to compute HHI index each year by group and then plot two trend lines.

Comment: See the comment below your question. PLease clarify what your expected outcome is. The calculation above does exactly what you mentioend. But it seems that this i not what you want, so please clarify. E.g. for year 1980, group 0 - what is the expected result? Same for year 1980 and group 1?

Comment: sorry, you are right. Maybe I wrongly put the formula. So I revised the formula. Could you then show me how to plot by group?

Comment: This doesn't change the results considerably, it just scales the result to be smaller now by the factor of 100. If your question is how to plot this data, please open a new question. Also because it is entirely unclear what `x` and `y` are in the plot.

Comment: x is supposed to be year and y HHI index. thanks